# Matrix de conexión de usuarios en Python/Spark

Tags: python, pyspark

Tengo un fichero donde se muestra las relaciones entre los ids de usuarios.

El fichero es de esta forma:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3
```

Quiero a través de python y spark conseguir una matrix de tamaño n_usuarios x n_usuarios como la siguiente, con un 1 en aquellos usuarios que están conectados y un 0 en el resto.

```
users 1 2 3
1    1 1 1
2    1 0 1 
3    1 0 1
```

Si me podéis ayudar con esto, he realizado pruebas con groupByKey pero no sé bien cómo implementarlo y me da problemas. 
Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Carlos, bienvenido a [es.so]. Estás en el sitio en español, por lo que debes traducir la pregunta para que se ajuste a las normas del sitio. Por otro lado, para formatear el código (y las matrices que pones de ejemplo, para que no se desestructuren) solo tienes que seleccionarlo y pulsar `Ctrl` + `k` o el botón `{}` del editor. Un saludo.

Comment: @CarlosGarcía recuerda que puedes usar la @ seguida de un nombre de usuario para que le llegue un reporte. Si no, no me entero ;)